# Flex: How can I retrieve the data before loading the components?

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, actionscript, components, mxml

In my flex application, my custom class AudLogDataGrid has a renderer function that takes a list of data and filters it, before passing it to the renderer:

```
        private function rendererFunction(item:Object, grid:Object):ClassFactory {  
            var itemRenderer:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(AudActionDropDownIR);
            var FilteredAudActionData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(AudActionData.toArray());
            ASTDForRow = item.AUD_STEP_TYPE_ID;
            FilteredAudActionData.filterFunction = filterTheData;
            FilteredAudActionData.refresh();
            (itemRenderer as AudActionDropDownIR).TheData = FilteredAudActionData;
            return itemRenderer;
        }
```

The AudActionData IList that is sorted is retrieved from a remote xml file using a custom HTTPService in the classes parent, which then is passed as a data binding:

```
<components:AudLogDataGrid id="AudLogGrid" y="131" left="10" right="10"
                           AudLogGridSelectionChange="AudLogGrid_AudLogGridSelectionChangeHandler(event)"
                           TheData="{getAudLogsResult.lastResult}"
                           AudActionData="{getAudActionsResult.lastResult}"/>
```

However, rendererFunction runs before the data is fully retrieve from the server! Is there any way to get around this without declaring the AudLogDataGrid in AS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected var filteredStuff:XMLListcollection = new XMLListCollection;
protected var cf:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(AudActionDropDownIR);
protected function creationComplete():void {//call from creationComplete "property" in MXML
    cf.properties= {TheData:filteredStuff};
    filteredStuff.filterFunction = filterTheData;//suggest you use e4x instead, but I can't give exact syntax without seeing your filterFunction
}

//when the data is returned:
protected function gotTheData(e:ResultEvent):void {
    filteredStuff.source = e.result.children as XMLList;
}
```

In the AudLogGrid MXML, just set cf as the itemRenderer.  The XMLListCollection should handle propogating changes to anything that has a reference to it (which all of your renderers now should.  This is far less memory-hogging than instantiating a new ClassFactory every time a renderer is needed.

BTW, you can override life cycle methods without writing the whole component in AS.  Just sayin'.